# Contact list isn't in Alphabetical order in Listview

Tags: android

I am using the Android Eclair 2.1 platform.

The working behind this code is, it will access all the contacts from the Emulator and will display in the list view for each contact like this

**Contact Name, Contact Number, Email**

There are 2 issues for this code is

1. I did run the program, after that I created a new contact it won't be in alphabetical order

[ eg : when I create a name starting from B it wouldn't go after A, instead it go to the last place ]

2.If a contact has no Email or Number it will receive the previous contact's Email or Number

Here is the code

```
public class GetAllDatas extends Activity { 

ListView lvItem;
private Button btnAdd;
String displayName="", emailAddress="", phoneNumber="";
ArrayList<String> contactlist=new ArrayList<String>(); 
ArrayAdapter<String> itemAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

lvItem = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.lvitems); 
btnAdd = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnAddItem);

itemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>    (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,contactlist);
lvItem.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    readContacts();
}
});

 } 

private void readContacts()
{
ContentResolver cr =getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,    null);
while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
{
displayName =Cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)    );       
String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
Cursor emails = cr.query(Email.CONTENT_URI,null,Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null,     null);
while (emails.moveToNext()) 
{ 
    emailAddress = emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA));
    break;
}
emails.close();
    if(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PH    ONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
{
    Cursor pCur =cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDat     aKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{id}, null);
    while (pCur.moveToNext()) 
    {
         phoneNumber =pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        break;  
    }
    pCur.close();
}

//  To display the Details
    contactlist.add(displayName+", "+phoneNumber+", "+ emailAddress+"\n");
    itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
cursor.close(); 
 }
 }
```

Any link or site to refer and study to solve this problems if so send me the link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the tested code below

```
package stack.examples;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class GetAllDatas extends Activity {

    ListView lvItem;
    private Button btnAdd;
    String displayName="", emailAddress="", phoneNumber="";
    ArrayList<String> contactlist=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> itemAdapter;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
       lvItem = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listView_items);  
       btnAdd = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnAddItem);
       itemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,contactlist);
       lvItem.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
       btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
               readContacts();
           }
       });
    }

    private void readContacts()
    {
        ContentResolver cr =getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
        {
            displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));       
            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            Cursor emails = cr.query(Email.CONTENT_URI,null,Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);
            while (emails.moveToNext()) 
            { 
                emailAddress = emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA));
                break;
            }
            emails.close();
            if(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
            {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) 
                {
                     phoneNumber = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    break;
                }
                pCur.close();
            }
                contactlist.add(displayName+","+phoneNumber+","+ emailAddress);

        }
        cursor.close(); 
        sortList(contactlist);
        itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private static void sortList(List<String> aItems){
        Collections.sort(aItems, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
      }
}
```

To sort the ArrayList in Alphabetical order, you can use

```
Collections.sort(aItems, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Happy Coding !!!

Comment: I need your help for very very small problem, When you come ?

Comment: please ask your question separately this may help others.

Comment: I have asked the question on this link  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095481/primary-data-is-only-coming )

Answer (score 0):

When you query the database you are missing the orderBy:

`public Cursor query (String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)`

replace the last null with the column to sort by:

```
Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,    null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The last parameter of the `query` method expects the sorting order.

Please check the documentation [`query (Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html).

> sortOrder How to order the rows, formatted as an SQL ORDER BY clause (excluding the ORDER BY itself). Passing null will use the default sort order, which may be unordered.