# Primary Data is only coming?

Tags: android

I am trying to access the Details of the contacts but I get only the primary details , I am using the Ecliar platform that means,

Now I get the **name, number** and the **email** ID of all contacts using this code.But If a contact having 2 numbers and 2 email IDs I get only the primary **number and Email ID**

I am using the display in the ListView like

1.Name 1, Number 1, email id 1.

2.Name 1, Number2, email Id 2. for the first person and so on

3.Name 2, number 1, email Id 1 for second person and so on.will continue like this.

But I get only the number1 and email ID 1 of a particular contact. Didn't get the number 2 and email id2 of that contact.

I edited the loop logic but it went to some other errors. How to solve this problem ?

**Code**

```
public class Details extends Activity {

ListView lvItem;
private Button btnAdd;
String emailAddress = "" ; 
String  displayName  = "" ;
String phoneNumber  = "" ; 
ArrayList<String> contactlist=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> itemAdapter;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
   lvItem = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listview);  
   btnAdd = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btn);
   itemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,contactlist);
   lvItem.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
   btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
          readContacts();

       }
   }); 
}


 private void readContacts()
{
    ContentResolver cr =getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
    {
        displayName  = "" ;
           ArrayList<String> phoneNumber  = new ArrayList<String>();
           ArrayList<String> emailAddress  = new ArrayList<String>();

        displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));       
        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

        Cursor emails = cr.query(Email.CONTENT_URI,null,Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);
        while (emails.moveToNext()) 
        { 
            emailAddress.add(emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA)));
            break;
        }
        emails.close(); 
        if(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
        {
            Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{id}, null);
            while (pCur.moveToNext()) 
            {
                 phoneNumber.add(pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
              break;  
            }  
            pCur.close();  
        }   

int phoneNumberCount = phoneNumber.size();
int emailCount = emailAddress.size();

// Add arraylist data to contactlist..

if(phoneNumberCount > emailCount) {

    for (int i=0; i<=phoneNumberCount; i++)
      {
        if(emailCount>i)
          {
           contactlist.add(displayName + " , " + phoneNumber.get(i) + " , " + emailAddress.get(i)+"\n");  
           }
        else
        {
          contactlist.add(displayName + " , " + phoneNumber.get(i)+"\n");
        }
       }
    }
    else 
       {
        for (int i=0; i<=emailCount; i++)
         {
        if(phoneNumberCount>i)
          {
            contactlist.add(displayName+", "+phoneNumber.get(i)+", "+ emailAddress.get(i)+"\n");
          }
        else
        {
            contactlist.add(displayName+","+ emailAddress.get(i)+"\n");
        } 
      }
    }     
    }
    Collections.sort(contactlist);
    itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    cursor.close(); 

 }
  }
```

Any Solution ?

**LogCat**

```
06-19 11:28:08.058: W/KeyCharacterMap(265): No keyboard for id 0
06-19 11:28:08.068: W/KeyCharacterMap(265): Using default keymap:     /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
06-19 11:28:33.187: D/dalvikvm(265): GREF has increased to 201
06-19 11:33:32.118: W/KeyCharacterMap(307): No keyboard for id 0
06-19 11:33:32.118: W/KeyCharacterMap(307): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
06-19 14:16:35.488: D/AndroidRuntime(385): Shutting down VM
06-19 14:16:35.498: W/dalvikvm(385): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
06-19 14:16:35.498: E/AndroidRuntime(385): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-19 14:16:35.507: E/AndroidRuntime(385): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid location 1, size is 1
06-19 14:16:35.507: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:341)
06-19 14:16:35.507: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at com.abhi.Trial3.readContacts(Trial3.java:100)
06-19 14:16:35.507: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at com.abhi.Trial3.access$0(Trial3.java:44)
06-19 14:16:35.507: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at com.abhi.Trial3$1.onClick(Trial3.java:38)
06-19 14:16:35.507: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
06-19 14:16:35.507: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
06-19 14:16:35.507: E/AndroidRuntime(385):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, replace `readContacts()` method from yours and let me know what happen..

```
private void readContacts()
{
    ContentResolver cr =getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
    {
        displayName  = "" ;
        ArrayList<String> phoneNumber  = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> emailAddress  = new ArrayList<String>();

        displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));       
        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

        Cursor emails = cr.query(Email.CONTENT_URI,null,Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);
        while (emails.moveToNext()) 
        { 
            emailAddress.add(emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA)));
            break;
        }
        emails.close(); 
        if(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
        {
            Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{id}, null);
            while (pCur.moveToNext()) 
            {
                 phoneNumber.add(pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
              break;  
            } 
            pCur.close();  
        }   

int phoneNumberCount = phoneNumber.size();
int emailCount = emailAddress.size();

// Add arraylist data to contactlist..

if(phoneNumberCount > emailCount) {

    for (int i=0; i<phoneNumberCount; i++)
      {
        if(emailCount>i)
          {
           contactlist.add(displayName + " , " + phoneNumber.get(i) + " , " + emailAddress.get(i)+"\n");    
           }
        else
        {
          contactlist.add(displayName + " , " + phoneNumber.get(i)+"\n");
        }
       }
    }
    else
       {
        for (int i=0; i<emailCount; i++)
         {
        if(phoneNumberCount>i)
          {
            contactlist.add(displayName+", "+phoneNumber.get(i)+", "+ emailAddress.get(i)+"\n");
          }
        else
        {
            contactlist.add(displayName+","+ emailAddress.get(i)+"\n");
        }
      }
    }     
    }
    Collections.sort(contactlist);
    itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    cursor.close(); 
}
```

Comment: On the section Add arraylist data to contactlist,it shows an Error on  main IF session of emailAddress.get(i) as the multiple markers at line delete this token.

Comment: ya the code has no error but application has stopped unexpectedly , I build the project and clean the project again and again  but it still remains......

Comment: @BigBoss: if you get logcat for above code, only you can post there, otherwise post in commands

Comment: Which change you are expecting for if(emailCount>i) and if(phoneNumberCount>i)

Comment: 99% it is OK. But all the details are coming together for EG: if abhi has 2 number and 2 emails the display will be Abhi, first number, first email as first row and abhi, second number, second email as second row. But now I get everything in a single row as abhi, firstnumber Secondnumber, first email secondemail. and so on ....you Got it ?

Comment: use this link for reference (https://mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com/attachment/u/0/?ui=2&ik=eff9917924&view=att&th=1380415cf752b770&attid=0.1&disp=inline&realattid=f_h3mrxywk0&safe=1&zw&saduie=AG9B_P8tqKDycYLg-j4GlV1swYLX&sadet=1340098373918&sads=8bYqYL0aJS2YKeyPkYb_tdG2r3s&sadssc=1)

Comment: I did what you told me on the code regarding of the = sign. Now I reedit the code and posted .please check it

Comment: Did you check the link. I am checking two codes simultaneously, these two codes give me the same answer.The code I edited above is your code as you told I removed the  = sign from the if loop. DO you get the answer by using your code?

Comment: i will check for your code  again and inform you because for the past  some hours you spend lot of time to me.

Comment: So your code is not working  has stopped unexpectedly.logcat errors are  Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception,,,
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid location 1, size is 1,,,
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:341),,,
at com.abhi.GetDetails.readContacts(GetDetails.java:104).

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the place to get live debugging.

Answer (score 0):

remove break in all while loop.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class StackOverFlowGetContactsActivity extends Activity {

    ListView lvItem;
    private Button btnAdd;
    String displayName="", emailAddress="", phoneNumber="";
    ArrayList<String> contactlist=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> itemAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> emailarray=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> phonearray=new ArrayList<String>();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
       lvItem = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listView_items);  
       btnAdd = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnAddItem);
       itemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,contactlist);
       lvItem.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
       btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
               readContacts();
           }
       });
    }

    private void readContacts()
    {
        ContentResolver cr =getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
        {
            displayName="";emailAddress=""; phoneNumber="";phonearray.clear(); emailarray.clear();
            displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));       
            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            Cursor emails = cr.query(Email.CONTENT_URI,null,Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);
            while (emails.moveToNext()) 
            { 
                emailarray.add(emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA)));
               // break;
            }
            emails.close();
            if(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
            {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) 
                {
                    phonearray.add(pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
                   // break;
                }
                pCur.close();
            }

            if(phonearray.size()>0)
            {
                for(int i=0; i<phonearray.size();i++)
                {
                    if(emailarray.size()>0)
                    {
                        for(int j=0; j<emailarray.size();j++)
                        {
                            emailAddress=emailarray.get(j);
                            phoneNumber=phonearray.get(i);
                            contactlist.add(displayName+","+phoneNumber+","+ emailAddress);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        phoneNumber=phonearray.get(i);
                        contactlist.add(displayName+","+phoneNumber+","+ emailAddress);                 
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                contactlist.add(displayName+","+phoneNumber+","+ emailAddress); 
            }

        }
        cursor.close(); 
        sortList(contactlist);
        itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private static void sortList(List<String> aItems){
        Collections.sort(aItems, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
      }
}
```

Comment: All the details are coming together for EG: if abhi has 2 number and 2  emails the display will be  Abhi, first number, first email as first row and abhi, second number, second email as second row. But now I get  everything in a single row as abhi, firstnumber Secondnumber, first email secondemail. and so on ....you Got it ?

Comment: for clarification use  this link ( https://mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com/attachment/u/0/?ui=2&ik=eff9917924&view=att&th=1380415cf752b770&attid=0.1&disp=inline&realattid=f_h3mrxywk0&safe=1&zw&saduie=AG9B_P8tqKDycYLg-j4GlV1swYLX&sadet=1340098373918&sads=8bYqYL0aJS2YKeyPkYb_tdG2r3s&sadssc=1 )

Comment: AKKA It shows some repitition like, the name having 2 num and 2 email: 
for the first number it uses two emails and for the second number it uses again the two emails . you got it what i am saying. So total 4 rows created . any doubt ask me .

Comment: how you want, can you please send any screenshot for this

Comment: So busy here ....mmm...how can I show you the screen short Let me send you a mail , mail ID is needed otherwise I write on this site itself. which one you prefer. ?

Comment: This is the image I got by using your code. I saved 2 numbers to Abhilash but it shows as repeated for each number. if u don't get me ask any question, after this I will explain the requirement. OK  ( http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=4j6vkk&s=6 )

Comment: This picture also contain Charan having no num and no email on display, but I saved 1 email to Charan, it didn't print, I thing this code will print the details if the contact having atleast number .